# If your perception of your voice is off, how can you sing at the correct pitch?

Tags: voice

When listening to a recording of your voice, it often sounds higher pitched than when you were speaking.  This has been [well researched](http://www.bbc.com/future/story/20130913-why-we-hate-hearing-our-own-voice) as being caused by you being able to hear some of your voice as vibrations through your bones, where the sound is lower.  In a recording your skull does not vibrate, leading to less bass, so your voice sounds higher.

However, it seems fairly easy to match the pitch of someone singing next to you.  How is this possible when your own perception of your voice is lower than what other people perceive you as?

Comment: Never perceived the *pitch* to be lower, although the *timbre* is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay.  I have just looked at the video on the link that you posted.

Is that well researched?  The guy just tells us "its like this".  No evidence, no suggestions of ways that you can test it, no reference to anything.  I'm not sure that what he says is enough to convince me.

But there is an experiment we can do easily:  Start singing a note and, whilst still singing it, put your fingers in your ears (i.e. try to stop the transmission of sound via the air route).  Did the pitch get lower when you put your fingers in your ears.  My perception is that the sound changed, acquiring more resonance but the pitch did not.

Ok my experiment may be flawed but I think that if what he said was true then I would have perceived some change in pitch.  I didn't.  So as a result of my "research" I would like to suggest that what we perceive is a change of quality of sound (Timbre as Tim puts it) rather than pitch.

Just my 2d.